# App logo not displaying while sharing a text in iOS - Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, share, flutter-ios

[image]

How to keep the App logo while sharing a text in Flutter ( iOS ) currently using [flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share) package.

```
await FlutterShare.share(
  title: title,
  text: url,
);
```

Any idea? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Same issue here, did you resolve it?